# Lowest break achieved in snooker

Tags: trivia, snooker

What is the lowest televised break achieved in snooker, where all balls were potted in the continuous break ?

So 15 reds with colours and all the colours.

Technically, although very unlikely, you could pot all 15 reds in a single shot (15) a yellow (2) and then all the colours (27) and the white goes in off the black (-7) so a score of 37 would be the lowest possible.

Comment: you're wrong - to count as a continious break, you have to combine a red with a yellow every time - so 15x(1+2) + 27 - 7 = 65

Comment: @Dirty-flow you can pot 2 reds with one shot and it is **NOT** a foul, therefore you could pot 15 reds with one shot and that too would not be a foul, anyway the question isn't around what is the technical lowest score, it is about the ACTUAL lowest score achieved in actual televised play

Comment: @Dirty-flow see example here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QFMOL04O-3I **this was not a foul**